# How to use Ambari API to Update Configs with a file

Tags: hadoop, ambari

So you can't directly update a single item, but must get the entire config group associated with.

What I have done is:

```
# read the tag of target config i want
curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X GET $BASE_URI?fields=Clusters/desired_configs > .temp_json

# download my configs
curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X GET "$BASE_URI/configurations?type=$CONFIG_TYPE&tag=$TARGET_TAG" > .configs_to_update

# update configs here > UPDATED_FILE_HERE

# ??? (upload the configs)
```

The next step is to upload the configs to the server then restart the services. I can't seem to figure out the API call to upload the configs. Does anyone know how I can upload the configs with the Ambari REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this helps your situation, but check out this command I use to make an adjustment to a single config:

```
python /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/scripts/configs.py -u admin -p admin -n HDP3 -l c7404.ambari.apache.org -t 8080 -a set -c cluster-env -k  ignore_groupsusers_create -v true
```